# NLP BERT in R with tensorflow/Keras setup

Tags: r, keras, bert-language-model, reticulate

I am trying to get BERT to run in R.

I got other NLP tasks (e.g. word2vec) done with Keras, so the general setup should be ok.

I adapted the model code from here: https://towardsdatascience.com/hugging-face-transformers-fine-tuning-distilbert-for-binary-classification-tasks-490f1d192379

The problem is how to insert the inputs (tokens) correctly. I have tried a lot of different ways to transform them (as tensors, various forms of arrays etc), but can't seem to figure out what kind of data structure/type/shape is expected as input.

Here is a simplified, replicable example:

```
#rm(list=ls())
packages <- c("reticulate", "keras", "tensorflow", "tfdatasets", "tidyverse", "data.table")
for (p in packages) if (!(p %in% installed.packages()[,1])) install.packages(p, character.only = TRUE) else require(p, character.only = TRUE)
rm(packages, p)

#reticulate::install_miniconda(force = TRUE) # 1time
reticulate::use_condaenv("~/.local/share/r-miniconda") # win? reticulate::use_condaenv("r-miniconda")

Sys.setenv(TF_KERAS=1) 
tensorflow::tf_version() # install_tensorflow() if NULL
reticulate::py_config()

#reticulate::py_install('transformers', pip = TRUE)
#reticulate::py_install('torch', pip = TRUE)
transformer = reticulate::import('transformers')
tf = reticulate::import('tensorflow')
builtins <- import_builtins() #built in python methods

set.tf.repos <- "distilbert-base-german-cased"

tokenizer <- transformer$AutoTokenizer$from_pretrained(set.tf.repos)  # 
tokenizer_vocab_size <- length(tokenizer$vocab)

###### load model
model_tf = transformer$TFDistilBertModel$from_pretrained(set.tf.repos, from_pt = T, trainable = FALSE)
model_tf$config

# set configs
model_tf$config$output_hidden_states = TRUE
summary(model_tf)

###### data & tokens #####
data <- data.table::fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michael-eble/nlp-dataset-health-german-language/master/nlp-health-data-set-german-language.txt", encoding = "Latin-1")
txt <- data$V1
y <- data$V2
table(y, exclude = NULL)

set.max_length = 100
tokens <- tokenizer(
  txt,
  max_length = set.max_length %>% as.integer(),
  padding = 'max_length', #'longest' #implements dynamic padding
  truncation = TRUE,
  return_attention_mask = TRUE,
  return_token_type_ids = FALSE
)
#tokens[["input_ids"]] %>% str()
#tokens[["attention_mask"]] %>% str()

tokens <- list(tokens[["input_ids"]], tokens[["attention_mask"]])
str(tokens)



####### model ########
input_word_ids <- layer_input(shape = c(set.max_length), dtype = 'int32', name = "input_word_ids")
input_mask <- layer_input(shape = c(set.max_length), dtype = 'int32', name = "input_attention_mask")
#input_segment_ids <- layer_input(shape = c(max_len), dtype = 'int32', name="input_segment_ids")

last_hidden_state <- model_tf(input_word_ids, attention_mask = input_mask)[[1]]
cls_token <- last_hidden_state[, 1,]

output <- cls_token %>%
  layer_dense(units = 32, input_shape = c(set.max_length, 768), activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid')

model <- keras_model(inputs = list(input_word_ids, input_mask), outputs = output)

model %>% compile(optimizer = "adam",
                  loss = "binary_crossentropy"
)

history = model %>%
  keras::fit(
    x = list(input_word_ids = tokens$input_ids, input_mask = tokens$attention_mask),
    y = y,
    epochs = 2,
    batch_size = 256,
    #metrics = "accuracy",
    validation_split = .2
  )
```

Error message:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: (<class 'dict'> containing {"<class 'str'>"} keys and {"<class 'NoneType'>"} values), <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Detailed traceback:
  File "/home/sz/.local/share/r-miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/sz/.local/share/r-miniconda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/data_adapter.py", line 984, in select_data_adapter
    raise ValueError(
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Which line causes the error? It seems the error is a reticulate error, literally stating "I got something I have no idea how to handle".

Comment: model %>% keras::fit() produces the error message.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, but I have no idea what kind of input is expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `model$inputs` shapes don't match the inputs you're feeding it in `fit()`.

It's helpful to create a TF Dataset, so you can be explicit about your training dataset tensor shapes, and make sure that those tensor shapes match `model$inputs`.

Changing your `fit()` call to this makes it work:

```
x_ds <- tensor_slices_dataset(tokens) 
y_ds <- tensor_slices_dataset(y)

ds <- zip_datasets(x_ds, y_ds) %>% 
  dataset_batch(256)

history = model %>% fit(ds, epochs = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! An awesomely elegant solution!